# Chrome Native Messaging “Native host has exited.” on python 3rd party package import

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome Extension that uses the native messaging feature to communicate with a Python script. As part of the Python script, I need to watch the file system, so I am pulling in [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) as a third party dependency. I've installed this package using pip, both globally and using a virtualenv, and I am pulling in two classes with the following lines in my script:

```
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer
```

It's all very simple. Here's where it gets weird. If I run the script using python on the command line it runs fine. Also, if I launch Chrome from the command line with the following command:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

The native script is successfully invoked by the Chrome extension. However, if I launch Chrome normally (just clicking the Chrome application icon), I get the following error right on startup:

```
Native host has exited.
```

If I remove both of the watchdog import lines from my script it runs fine. I'm pretty stuck, as I don't seem to have a way of debugging the problem given that it works when I launch the script from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[Debugging native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-debugging) states that error `Native host has exited.` is due to:

> The pipe to the native messaging host was broken before the message was read by Chrome. This is most likely initiated from your native messaging host.

As stated in the documentation:

> Native applications that support native messaging **must register a native messaging host** that knows how to communicate with the extension.The application must install a manifest file which must be a valid JSON and contains the required fields that defines the native messaging host configuration to register a host as shown in example below:

```
{
  "name": "com.my_company.my_application",
  "description": "My Application",
  "path": "C:\\Program Files\\My Application\\chrome_native_messaging_host.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}
```

You may also check [examples/api/nativeMessaging](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging) for sample application that uses native messaging to communicate with a Python script that serves as a native messaging host.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but if you read my post, the issue is specifically with importing that third party package. In relation to your suggestions, I have got it working with Google's example. It works with their example if I import watchdog and start Chrome from the command line, but it does not work with their example if I import watchdog and launch Chrome using the Application icon.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem went away when I did `pip install <package>` outside of the venv my IDE terminal was using. It should also be possible to cause the host script to load using the venv, perhaps with a wrapper shell script calling the venv python binary.